# Linear Tranformation that preserves Direct sum $ V = ImT \oplus \ KerT $

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following:   $\ \ \   Im L \oplus KerL = V \ \ $   when $\ \ \ L = T^k \ \ \ $ When: $\mathbb T: V \rightarrow V  \  $ and   $  ImT \oplus KerT =V$

My take on this is below. I would like to know if  my proof is a proper one? If not can you point me to where it fails? Any comment's and suggestions would be much appreciated

Proof:
Assuming $ S = T^2 $ then  $ KerS = \{ v \in V  \ | \ T(T(v))=0 \ \} \ \Rightarrow \{ \ T(v) \ \in KerT \ and \ \ \ T(v) \in \ ImT \ \}$

Since $ImT$ and $KerT$ are a direct sum we have $ KerS = \{ \ 0 \ \} $ and since we have $$ dimImS \ + \ dimKerS \ = dimV $$ we get $$ V = Im S \Rightarrow \ V = KerS \oplus \ ImS$$

Now we move on to $ H = T^3 $

Since $ ImS = V\ \ \  and \ \ \ ImS\cap KerT =KerT \ \ $ we get $  \ \ KerH = KerT , \ ImH=ImT\ \ \   $ Which means $ V = ImH\oplus KerH $

The relationship above is cyclical for odd and even $k$'s, so it's true for all  $K$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $v\in \ker(S)$ where $S=T^2$ then as you noted correctly, we have $T(v)\in \ker(T)\cap Im(T)$ which is $0$, so $T(v)=0$ and therefore $v\in \ker(T)$. On the other hand, if $v\in Im(S)$, then there is $w\in V$ such that $T^2(w)=v$ or $T(T(w))=v$ and so $v\in Im(T)$ as well. Since $\ker(T)\bigoplus Im(T)=V$ so $v=0$. This shows that: $$\ker(S)\cap Im(S)=0$$ $S=T^2$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $V$, so if the dimention of $V$ is finite we have $\ker(S)+Im(S)=V$ and hence $\ker(S)\oplus Im(S)=V$. For  the rest, I think, induction will help us.